# How to name (BTC/AUD) / USD rate?

Tags: currency, terminology

I am buying the BTC in Australian Dollars (AUD):
`BTC/AUD`
I want to convert this rate (`BTC/AUD`) to American Dollars (USD).
So, I have the following rate:
`(BTC/AUD) / BUSD`
What's the name for rates like this? Maybe, cross rate?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert the BTC/AUD ratio to a BTC/USD ratio? If I interpret what you said literally ("convert BTC/AUD to USD"), then it doesn't make any sense, because one is a ratio and the other is an amount of money. Trying to convert a ratio to an amount of money is like trying to convert a speed to degrees Celsius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no name for it because there's no such thing.

You can:

- sell USD and get AUD
- sell USD and get BTC
- sell BTC and get AUD
- sell X and get Y

In each case, depending on your volume, you will get a certain price.

What you are describing doesn't exist.

Also, you cannot "convert" a price.  What does that mean?  Say I told you I sold a house in Smith St for $Y.  And you said "oh I want to `convert` that to a price for a house in Jones St."  What does it mean?  It has no meaning.

(Also to be clear.  When you say you want to convert "a rate"... "rate" is literally another word for "price".  If you buy 200 units of BTC and you paid 333 units of CHF, the price you paid was "333".  Rate is just the same: 333/200. You can't "convert" a rate, it's meaningless.)